# Algorithm used to generate most popular item

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a site of articles using php and mysql... I am storing view rate and like rate of

an article in database in different field... Now i want to select most popular article of a

day (means today), month and year based on view rate and like rate... Is there any algorithm

for finding most popular article using these data....?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you just sort them using `order by` ?

Comment: Of course. Just select any rating related values from today or this month or this year, group by them by article, sum them to a score, and finally order by this score. If you provided some detailed table schematics and some solutions, you tried so far, we would happily help you.

Comment: @Basti : What u mean by rating related values?.. My table fields are articledid, viewcount, likecount , createdtime..

Comment: If you want to display the most liked articles of today, you will have to save the time on which a like has been given to this article. If you don't store this information, you can not distinguish a like from today from a like 3 months ago. I assumed you had some kind of table for your likes with columns `article_id`, `liked_at`.

Answer (score 1):

To get Statistics Monthly statistics for year 2012

```
select page_id,sum(views) from tableName 
where year(recordDate)='2012'
group by page_id, group by month(recordDate)
```

Comment: +1 For the record, since MySQL does not provide function based indexes like `year(recordDate)` this query can get slow for large amounts of data. To speed this up, you could just have additional separate columns for `year` and `month`, e.g. (2012-03-12, 2012-03, 2012). You can create an index on each column and have a nicely performing query.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the likes as single objects in the database like in this kind of table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `like` (
    `article_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `liked_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
    PRIMARY KEY (  `article_id` ,  `user_id` ) ,
    INDEX (  `liked_at` )
);
```

Every time a user likes an article you inside a row (article_id, user_id, NOW()) into this table.

To get the top article, just select any tuples from today or this month or this year, group by them by article_id, count(article_id) as score, and finally order by this score.

To get today's 5 most liked articles:

```
SELECT article_id, count(user_id) as score
FROM like
WHERE liked_at > NOW() - 86400
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 5
```

`WHERE liked_at > NOW() - 86400` only selects likes that are not older than 24h.

If you know that you will only want today's, this month's and this year's like count, you can have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE  `article` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `likes_today` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
    `likes_this_month` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
    `likes_this_year` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0'
);
```

For every like you increment the article's `likes_today`, `likes_this_month` and `likes_this_year` by one. Once a day you set `likes_today` to `0` for all articles. Once a month you set `likes_this_month` to `0` for all articles.

Today's 5 most liked article:

```
SELECT id, likes_today
FROM article
ORDER BY likes_today DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Beware that I used two different meanings for `today`. In the first example `today` means `not older than 24 hours`. In the second example `today` means `since last reset`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title FROM today WHERE viewed DESC ./day
SELECT title FROM month WHERE viewed DESC ./day
SELECT title FROM year WHERE viewed DESC ./day
```

cinda explains what im trying to say :D